# ASP.NET GridView twice executes SelectMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have problem with my GridView. I have a basic `<asp:GridView>` like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GvMyFirstViewList" runat="server"
     SkinID="GvSkinList" EnableViewState="false" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true"
     EmptyDataText="Empty" DataKeyNames="Id" PageSize="2"
     ItemType="MyFirstView" SelectMethod="GetAll">
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Firstname">
              <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litFirstname" Text='<%# Item.FirstName %>'></asp:Literal>
         </asp:TemplateField>        
         //other columns
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My select method `GetAll` returns an `IQueryable` of elements from the database. I have several records in the database to display, I want to show two elements on the page of the grid.

When I load the page, `GetAll` runs once, but when I click on the third page, `GetAll` executes from the first page and the third page, next I click fifth page and `GetAll` executes for third page and fifth page etc.

I don't know why, and how to fix this.

Comment: I don't get your question. Are you talking about GridView paging? If so then what you are seeing is normal behaviour.

Comment: This is what I mean GridView paging. In that case, in what way to get to the elements from the page I click, omitting elements that load from the previous page. Do I have an event that will only be done once for the page you click?